# Запись в SQL таблицу сортированных данных?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb

Есть примерно такой код. Что здесь не так и почему я не могу записать название компании в другую таблицу?

```
INSERT INTO wpv4_wpdatatable_7 (Company_name)
SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Назва компанії:',     field_value, NULL)) AS Company_name,
    MAX(IF(field_name = "Ім'я:",    field_value, NULL)) AS User_Name,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Email',      field_value, NULL)) AS Email,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Номер телефона',      field_value, NULL)) AS Phone,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Відповідальний',      field_value, NULL)) AS Manager,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'ЄДРПОУ',      field_value, NULL)) AS Code_Company,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'ІПН (для платників ПДВ)',      field_value, NULL)) AS IPN,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Посада підписанта',      field_value, NULL)) AS Sign_Role,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'П.І.Б. Підписанта (у родовому відмінку)',      field_value, NULL)) AS ПІБ Підписанта,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'На підставі чого діє',      field_value, NULL)) AS Sign_LAW,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Місто',      field_value, NULL)) AS City,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Вулиця',      field_value, NULL)) AS Street,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Назва Банку',      field_value, NULL)) AS bank_name,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'IBAN',      field_value, NULL)) AS Iban,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Нова Пошта №:',      field_value, NULL)) AS NP№,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Тел. отримувача',      field_value, NULL)) AS NP_Phone,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'П.І.Б для сертифіката',      field_value, NULL)) AS NP_PIB

FROM
    wpv4_contactic_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
```

В начальной таблице есть одна строка со всеми значениями. Я ее разбил на столбцы.Теперь данные столбцы нужно записать в другую таблицу.

Comment: Почему вы используете Max на строке. Вам не подходит order by? В остальном как заметил Alex R или добавьте остальные столбцы в INSERT или уберите лишнее столбцы из SELECT

Answer (score 1):

При использовании оператора `INSERT` количество вставляемых колонок и значений для них должно быть одинаковым.

Вставляется только одна колонка `INSERT INTO wpv4_wpdatatable_7 (Company_name)`, а в запросе их больше.

Попробуйте так:

```
INSERT INTO wpv4_wpdatatable_7 (Company_name)
SELECT
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'Назва компанії:',     field_value, NULL)) AS Company_name
FROM
    wpv4_contactic_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
```

Или допишите остальные имена колонок после `Company_name`.

Comment: Выдает:  INTO not implemented

Comment: синтаксис верный, я проверил на тесте. Какой код ошибки? Отдельно `select` выполняется?

Comment: R Ошибка: #1064

Comment: @MorisNazar приведите полный текст ошибки. 1064 это incorrect synatax, а ни какой не "into not impemented". И в тексте ошибки 1064 в конце написано где именно споткнулся анализатор. И текст запроса заодно, если он хоть на символ отличается от того, что написан в ответе